# Asp.net Identity: cannot convert from CustomUserRole to IdentityUserRole

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

Newbie here, I am experiencing the following error and I have no idea how to resolve the issue. I did change the primary key for users in Identity to int rather than it being stored as a string.(I believe that is what's causing the issue). Besides that, every other page runs perfectly. Any ideas on where to start?

**CS1503    Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<DraftIntellectualProperty.Models.CustomUserRole>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole>'**

The error: [image: Manage.aspx]

The method being called in the code-behind: [image: Manage.aspx.cs]

Snip from IdentityModel: [image: IdentityModel.cs]

Snip from IdentityUserRole class: [image: IdentityUserRole]

Comment: Please don't add screen shots of code, but rather write the code in the post.

Comment: Have you tried `ICollection<IdentityUserRole<int>> userRoles` as your ListRoles parameter?